# Background does not extend after scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background, overflow

The [screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbIbV.jpg) should explain my issue very well.
Keep in mind that the height which I gave to the background is `height: 100vh;`. so It covers the initial view of the page.
The problem arrives when the inner divs overflow and the background does not extend when I scroll down. I already have tried `overflow: hidden;` and `overflow: scroll;`

This is the HTML code inside the `<body>` element. I am also using bootstrap for styling so you may see some bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="search sidebar-btn" sidebar-btn>
            <input class=" shadow-sm search-area" type="text" placeholder="search">
            <div class="shadow-sm search-icon"><img class="magnifying-glass" src="assets/magnifying-glass.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div><a href="#" class="sidebar-btn btn btn-dark">Home</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="sidebar-btn btn btn-dark">Profiles</a></div>
        <div><a href="#" class="sidebar-btn btn btn-dark">About Us</a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-area" class="page">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="card polaroid">
                <img src="image1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Placeholder</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card polaroid">
                <img src="image2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Placeholder</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card polaroid">
                <img src="image3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Placeholder</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card polaroid">
                <img src="image4.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Placeholder</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the css. The file is too long and messy therefore I only included the relevent classes.

```
.flex {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;}

.sidebar {  
background-image: url("assets/wall.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: 20vw;
height: 100vh;
border-right: 2px solid #0097A7;}

#main-area{
width: 80vw;
height: 100vh;
background-image: url("background.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;}

.holder{
padding: 15px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
position: absolute;
justify-content: space-around;}
```

Comment: 100vh is the height of the browser window. NOT the height of the HTML page... Use a different unit for height. Or set `min-height: 100vh` so that its "at least" that tall.

Comment: use `height: 100vh; background-attachmnt: fixed;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed;` and remove the height for `sidebar` and `main-area`, in this way the background will stay in place. I also removed `position: absolute;` for class `holder`.

This is the complete CSS code:

```
.flex {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar {  
background-image: url("assets/wall.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
width: 20vw;
border-right: 2px solid #0097A7;}

#main-area{
width: 80vw;
background-image: url("background.jpg");
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.holder{
padding: 15px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```